# How is Market Value of players calculated in Fifa 2012?

Tags: ios, fifa-12

In Fifa 2012 (iOS edition at least) the career mode allows one to buy and sell players. Each player has an associated market value. How are these values calculated?

(I assume it is somehow related to performance and such...but as a manager, I should be able to get an accurate understanding of the calculation. The app is woefully under documented.)

When buying a player, I want to make a reasonable offer, but not overdo it. If current value is 150,000 with 1000 per Game, what is a good counter offer? What would be the new offer's equivalent market value be?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how different the iOS edition is, but from what I've been observing, the market value depends mainly on AGE and OVR (form may also be considered, not sure).

A player of around 23-25 age with 85 OVR has much more market value than a player of age 30-33 with same OVR. I've also observed the player in good form is in more demand which contributes to increase in market value.

Even if the player has a value of $25million, OVR: 85, AGE: 25, when you actually bid for him, the club responds by asking for increasing the bid way higher than the market value (like $50million).